# NASM: undefined reference to `print_string' and similar erros

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86, nasm

I have been reading from Paul A. Carter's PC Assembly Language book to learn assembly and got to a part where there is actual coding. I have limited assembly knowledge, and have only made small programs using MASM in the past. I installed NASM and I have been coding assembly in VS code. I have a MinGW file in my C: drive that is the path (I am not 100% sure if that is the correct terminology).

I have been trying to get this code to work

```
; file: first.asm
; First assembly program. This program asks for two integers as
; input and prints out their sum.
;
; To create executable using djgpp:
; nasm -f coff first.asm
; gcc -o first first.o driver.c asm_io.o

 %include "asm_io.inc"
 extern print_string
;
; initialized data is put in the .data segment
;
segment .data
;
; These labels refer to strings used for output
;
prompt1 db "Enter a number: ", 0 ; don’t forget null terminator
prompt2 db "Enter another number: ", 0
outmsg1 db "You entered ", 0
outmsg2 db " and ", 0
outmsg3 db ", the sum of these is ", 0

;
; uninitialized data is put in the .bss segment
;
segment .bss
;
; These labels refer to double words used to store the inputs
;
input1 resd 1
input2 resd 1

;
; code is put in the .text segment
;
segment .text
global _asm_main
_asm_main:
enter 0,0 ; setup routine
pusha

mov eax, prompt1 ; print out prompt
call print_string

call read_int ; read integer
mov [input1], eax ; store into input1

mov eax, prompt2 ; print out prompt
call print_string

call read_int ; read integer
mov [input2], eax ; store into input2

mov eax, [input1] ; eax = dword at input1
add eax, [input2] ; eax += dword at input2
mov ebx, eax ; ebx = eax

dump_regs 1 ; print out register values
dump_mem 2, outmsg1, 1 ; print out memory
;
; next print out result message as series of steps
;
mov eax, outmsg1
call print_string ; print out first message
mov eax, [input1]
call print_int ; print out input1
mov eax, outmsg2
call print_string ; print out second message
mov eax, [input2]
call print_int ; print out input2
mov eax, outmsg3
call print_string ; print out third message
mov eax, ebx
call print_int ; print out sum (ebx)
call print_nl ; print new-line

popa
mov eax, 0 ; return back to C
leave
ret
```

This is the code from the book itself. I noticed the GitHub for the course has another "first" program but that one only gave me more trouble and seemed to be different from the one in the book. I call a batch file to run the program:

```
set ProjectName=first
nasm -f win32 %ProjectName%.asm
gcc %ProjectName%.obj -o %ProjectName%.exe
%ProjectName%.exe
```

This is what outputs after running this command:

```
C:\Users\jackg\OneDrive\Desktop\CS & ADL\assembly\assembly1>compileNASM.bat

C:\Users\jackg\OneDrive\Desktop\CS & ADL\assembly\assembly1>set ProjectName=first

C:\Users\jackg\OneDrive\Desktop\CS & ADL\assembly\assembly1>nasm -f win32 first.asm

C:\Users\jackg\OneDrive\Desktop\CS & ADL\assembly\assembly1>gcc first.obj -o first.exe
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: first.obj:first.asm:(.text+0xb): undefined reference to `print_string'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: first.obj:first.asm:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `read_int'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: first.obj:first.asm:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `print_string'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: first.obj:first.asm:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `read_int'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: first.obj:first.asm:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `sub_dump_regs'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: first.obj:first.asm:(.text+0x4b): undefined reference to `sub_dump_mem'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: first.obj:first.asm:(.text+0x55): undefined reference to `print_string'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: first.obj:first.asm:(.text+0x5f): undefined reference to `print_int'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: first.obj:first.asm:(.text+0x69): undefined reference to `print_string'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: first.obj:first.asm:(.text+0x73): undefined reference to `print_int'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: first.obj:first.asm:(.text+0x7d): undefined reference to `print_string'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: first.obj:first.asm:(.text+0x84): undefined reference to `print_int'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: first.obj:first.asm:(.text+0x89): undefined reference to `print_nl'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xc0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

C:\Users\jackg\OneDrive\Desktop\CS & ADL\assembly\assembly1>first.exe
'first.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Additionally I have the `asm_io.asm` and `asm_io.inc` files in the same location as the `first.asm` file. I also ran `nasm -f win32 -d COFF_TYPE asm_io.asm` to make the object file.

I am not sure where to go from here. I have searched around inline for answers on how to set everything up or what might be wrong but I can't find any. Let me know how I could fix this and any tips or necessary components needed for the book!

Comment: Look again at the link command in the comment: `gcc -o first first.o driver.c asm_io.o`.  It'll be `.obj` instead of `.o` for you.  You say you built `asm_io.obj` but you still have to include it in the link command line.  And `driver.c` seems to have gotten lost altogether.

Comment: You may encounter other difficulties in porting from djgpp to MinGW.  For instance, I'm not certain, but MinGW when compiling C may name external symbols starting with `_`, so all your calls to functions and variables defined in `driver.c` would have to change to `_print_string` and so forth.  I am also not sure whether the calling conventions agree; if not then you have to rewrite all those function calls.

Comment: If you're just starting in learning assembly, you'll probably greatly reduce frustration by reading a tutorial that matches the OS you are going to build and run on (perhaps in a virtual machine).  With [WSL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) I believe you could follow an x86-64 Linux tutorial while continuing to use Windows.

Comment: @NateEldredge when I tried running the command you gave I got the error `gcc: error: driver.c: No such file or directory`. I'm assuming this is because my c/c++ is in the wrong location, but not sure. Additionally, I saw the tutorial said to install djgpp but I thought MinGW would be fine. Will installing djgpp have consequences on other programs I have written in C++ and will I have to re-route some things? Lastly, is there an advantage to using WSL2 over switching to tutorials that are focused on windows? I only ask this because I was having a lot of trouble finding material to learn from.

Comment: `driver.c` is another source file that is part of the program.  It's probably where the functions `print_string`, `read_int` and especially `WinMain` are supposed to be defined.  Your program can't build because you In context it looks like it should have been provided as part of the tutorial.  Was it not?

Comment: DJGPP is a compiler for DOS.  You can use it if you want, and it's great if you miss the '90s, but it's definitely more of historical than practical interest in today's world.  Some of the things you learn will be broadly applicable, some will not.  I don't think it would interfere with any other compiler installation but I don't know for sure.

Comment: As to Linux via WSL2 versus native Windows, I think it really depends on which you are interested in knowing more about.  My impression is that assembly is a little easier to learn under Linux which has simpler ABIs, but that could just be that I happen to be more familiar with it.

Comment: The [x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) has a great collection of learning resources, curated by people who really know what they're talking about.  You should check it out if you haven't.  (I also added the x86 tag to your question, by the way.  [tag:assembly] questions should always have an architecture tag as well.)